# Why partition is needed in Shopify Sarama consumer to consume messages

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I am sorry for posting a question related to a Kafka Library as not many people are interested in Library specific questions. But this library is one of the most used library for golang-Kafka implementations.

I want to create a simple consumer using Sarama library which listens to a topic. Now as far as I know, in the high-level Kafka API's, by default a consumer listens to all the topics partitions if a specific partition is not specified. However, in this Library, the Consumer interface has only ConsumePartition function where the partition is required param. The signature of function is:

```
ConsumePartition(topic string, partition int32, offset int64) (PartitionConsumer, error)
```

This confuses me a bit. Anyone who has worked on it?

Also, I have a basic question regarding Kafka. If I have a consumer group consisting of 3 consumer instances and they are listening to let's say 2 topics each having 2 partitions, then do I need to specifically mention which consumer instance will consume to which partition or Kafka Fetch API will take care of it on its own based on load?

Comment: no update on this? @Rishabh

Answer (score 3):

I use [sarama-cluster](https://github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster) which is an open source extension for Sarama (also recommended by [Shopify Sarama](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#Consumer)).
With Sarama cluster you can create a consumer using this API:

```
cluster.NewConsumer(brokers, consumerGroup, topics, kafkaConfig)
```

so no partition is needed. You should only provide the addresses of your Kafka `brokers`, the name of your `consumer group` and which `topics` you wish to consume.

---

[Consumers handling](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)

To maintain order you should assign to each partition only one consumer.
So in case you have 3 consumers in your consumer group and you want them to consume 2 topics having 2 partitions each, you should assign as follows:

```
partitions 1,2 -> consumer A  
partition 3 -> consumer B  
partition 4 -> consumer C
```

You might end up with one of the consumers advancing faster (one of the topics have higher throughput) and you will need to re-balance.
Using a library (like sarama-cluster) that handles this for you is recommended.

Comment: Just found out that meanwhile the project has been officially deprecated b/c of https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/pull/1099 (which addresses consumer groups), so I posted an updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile the Sarama cluster project has been *deprecated*, see the [Deprecation Notice](https://github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster#deprecation-notice) in their repo. The good news it has been deprecated in favor of the PR [Implement a higher-level consumer group #1099](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/pull/1099),
which focusses on consuming topic(s) rather than dedicated partitions.

The `examples/` folder in the official sarama repo provides a good [Consumer Group Implementation Example](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/examples/consumergroup/main.go). It works like a charm and doesn't require any additional libraries on top of Sarama.

Preview:

```
config := sarama.NewConfig()
client, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroup(strings.Split(brokers, ","), "mygroup", config)
client.Consume(ctx, strings.Split(topics, ","), &consumer) // should run in a loop
```