# Sarama Partition Consumer with ConsumerGroup

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I have tried shopify/sarama library to consume kafka messages. I used both `Consumer` interface and `ConsumerGroup` interface. I can consume from specific partitions using `ConsumePartition()` method in `Consumer`. But when I use `ConsumerGroup` interface, I do not seem to have the capability to consume from a specific partition.

Is there a way for me to assign certain partitions to specific consumers inside a consumer group? Or is it something I cannot interfere with?

Comment: Try using the assign() method of the KafkaConsumer. You can assign a specific partition using this.

Comment: @fatemasagar assign() method is in `confluent` kafka library, right? There is no such method in `sarama` library.

Comment: Yes, Dean, you are correct about that. Sorry for that answer.

Comment: The Java API allows assigning within a consumer group. I'd be surprised if sarama didn't

Comment: this strange to me as well...not aware much with sarama however this may be benfit to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279935/why-partition-is-needed-in-shopify-sarama-consumer-to-consume-messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like I cannot give exact partitions to consume when using `ConsumerGroup`. However I can choose the strategy that I want to assign partitions to my consumers, out of 2 strategy options.

1. Balance Strategy Range

BalanceStrategyRange is the default and assigns partitions as ranges to consumer group members.
Example with one topic T with six partitions (0..5) and two members (M1, M2):

```
M1: {T: [0, 1, 2]}
M2: {T: [3, 4, 5]}
```

2. Balance Strategy Round-Robin

BalanceStrategyRoundRobin assigns partitions to members in alternating order.
Example with topic T with six partitions (0..5) and two members (M1, M2):

```
M1: {T: [0, 2, 4]}
M2: {T: [1, 3, 5]}
```

I can give this as a configuration when creating the ConsumerGroup.

```
config.Consumer.Group.Rebalance.Strategy = BalanceStrategyRange
```